# With 3 number print 3 different case

Tags: java

int a, b, c;

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Inserire a");
a = scan.nextInt();
System.out.println("Inserire b");
b = scan.nextInt();
System.out.println("Inserire c");
c = scan.nextInt();

if (a == b && a == c){
    System.out.println("All the same");
}

if (((a==b) && b!=c) || ((a==c) && (b!=c)) || ((b == c) && (a!= c)));
{
    System.out.println("Two the same and one different ");
}
else 
    {
    System.out.print(" All different");
    }
else if (( a != b)  && (b != c) && (a != c));
{
            System.out.println("Tutti diversi");
}
```

scan.close();
}

I m getting error for the else, and the program read all the 3 different cases
and print out the 3 print.

Comment: you have an else if after an else... I bet that the IDE tells exactly that...

Comment: You cannot have an `else` after an `else`, only after an `if`. Voting to close as typo. Waiting for people to post an answer to try to earn easy rep.

Comment: I get the Syntax error on token "else"

Comment: And if I run the program, it prints me out everything

Comment: @ChistreamofconsciousnessSo Even "Tutti diversi"?

Comment: In general, syntax errors can and should be fixed at compile time, not after running the code. So, read the IDE error message and act accordingly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to do something like this as having an else if after an else for the same block will cause you issues. If this is not the behavior you are looking for please supply more info and I'll try to help :)

```
int a, b, c;

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Inserire a");
a = scan.nextInt();
System.out.println("Inserire b");
b = scan.nextInt();
System.out.println("Inserire c");
c = scan.nextInt();

if (a == b && a == c){
     System.out.println("All the same");
}

else if (((a==b) && b!=c) || ((a==c) && (b!=c)) || ((b == c) && (a!= c)));
{
    System.out.println("Two the same and one different ");
}
else 
{
    System.out.println("Tutti diversi");
    System.out.print(" All different");
}
```

Comment: now It prints out "all the same" and "all different"

Comment: answer updated. try that and what input are you using

Comment: yess I have to wait 5 minutes and then I can accept the answer,

Comment: you don't need to check that `b!=c` or `a!=c`. Since you are not in the first `if`, they are different! The else if could be simply: `else if (a==b || b==c || a==c)`

Answer (score 0):

Try using else if instead of the second if an cut paste the else part after all the else if s.

Answer (score 0):

If you've indented your code well then you've figured out that:

You have `if-else-else` instead of `if-else-if-else`

```
if (a == b && a == c){
    System.out.println("All the same");
}

if (((a==b) && b!=c) || ((a==c) && (b!=c)) || ((b == c) && (a!= c)));  //Also you have a ";" here, why?
{
    System.out.println("Two the same and one different ");
}
else 
    {
    System.out.print(" All different");
    }
else if (( a != b)  && (b != c) && (a != c)); //here's your error
{
            System.out.println("Tutti diversi");
}
```

How to solve it?

```
if (a == b && a == c){
    System.out.println("All the same");
} 

if (((a==b) && b!=c) || ((a==c) && (b!=c)) || ((b == c) && (a!= c)))
{
    System.out.println("Two the same and one different ");
}
else 
{
    System.out.print(" All different");
}
if (( a != b)  && (b != c) && (a != c));
{
            System.out.println("Tutti diversi");
}
```